# How to locate files in webstorm nodejs require

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm

How do I know when to use `../` or `./` or even `..//` when trying to find a file on webstorm? For example what is happening here is it starting from the top folder or:

```
var Schema = require('./.services/.router.js');
```

Comment: This may help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Representations_of_paths_by_operating_system_and_shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

./ means you want to access your current directory

../ means you want to access first parent of current directory

For example: when in /home/my/directory/ the ../ will get you into /home/my/